# Return 0 no Linux e Windows

Tags: c, c++, linux, sintaxe, return

Estou começando o curso de ADS e meu professor de programação insiste em usar o `return 0` no fim da função. A maioria usa Windows, percebi que o `return 0` é necessário no Windows mas no Ubuntu (que é o que eu uso) eu não coloco `return` 0 mas mesmo assim o programa roda normalmente sem nenhum erro.

Por que o `return 0` se faz necessário no Windows mas não no Linux? Tem algo a ver com o compilador usado? Usei tanto o `g++` quanto o `gcc` no terminal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isso nada tem a ver com o sistema operacional, tem a ver com o compilador. Provavelmente está usando o Microsoft VC++ no Windows e o GCC no Linux. Na verdade pode até depender de configuração.

Tem compilador que pode decidir que uma função tem sempre um `return` do tipo especificado implícito se não colocar algo. Tem compilador que obriga ser explícito para evitar sair da função de forma indesejada. Como a especificação não fala nada sobre isso nem obrigando, nem proibindo, cada um faz como quer.

Isso vale para qualquer função, o fato de ser no `main()` é só uma coincidência. Então como o `main()` foi declarado como retorno `int`, sempre haverá o retorno do 0 se nada for retornado explicitamente. Note que o `main()` nem precisa ser chamada pelo sistema operacional, ela é uma função comum.

De forma geral é mais legível e evita *bugs* escrever o retorno explicitamente, mas no caso do `main()` e for algo simples não vejo maiores problemas, ainda mais em exercícios, eu tenho evitado.

Comment: Meu professor não soube me explicar isso, eu também pesquisei em fóruns e não achei nada relativo. Agradeço muito pela sua resposta, me tirou uma dúvida que eu tinha já fazia tempo. Sou novo por aqui então peço perdão caso eu tenha feito a pergunta de forma indevida.

Comment: Está tudo certo. Procure estudar por várias fontes e entender o porquê das coisas. Está no caminho certo não se conformando como "as coisas são assim".