# Como funciona o retorno das funções em C?

Tags: c, funções, tipagem, return

Pelo que andei vendo toda função em C precisa de um retorno, estou certo ou não?

1- Qual o porquê disso? Influencia em algo? (Gostaria de uma explicação lógica se possível).

2- No caso do `main()`, o tipo de retorno irá influenciar em algo, independente de ser 0, 10, 20, S, AB, 1000...?

Porque numa função a parte o retorno irá influenciar a onde está fazendo sua chamada, certo? Aí fiquei com essa dúvida no retorno do `main()`.

3- Mesmo para as funções do tipo `void` é necessário colocar um retorno?

4- Só para confirmar, no caso o retorno está relacionado ao tipo que foi setado na função, correto? Então se eu setar como `int`, não adianta ter um retorno em `float` pois irá ocasionar erro, ok?

Se tiver mais algumas informações, dicas, sugestões para passar a respeito desse assunto estou a disposição.

Comment: Por definição uma função sempre retorna alguma coisa, que você pode ou não usar. Em C não temos o conceito de procedimento mas você pode simular definindo o tipo de retorno da função como void, indicando que não se fará uso do retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> toda função em C precisa de um retorno, estou certo ou não?
>
> 1- Qual o porquê disso? Influencia em algo?

Por que quase todas funções geram um resultado. No conceito matemático todas resultam em algo, não faz sentido uma função resultar em algo, ela foi criada para isto. Então é assim para sintetizar o conceito matemático e também porque é mais fácil manter uma sintaxe de forma linear e não ter que lidar com um jeito diferente de fazer.

Em programação faz sentido ter algumas rotinas que não gerem um resultado, em geral isto é chamado de *procedure*, mas convencionou-se usar o tipo `void` da função para indicar que é um procedimento e não uma função real, pelo motivo explicado acima. Veja mais em [Qual a diferença entre funções e procedimentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101).

Isto pode ajudar também: [Porque usar somente return, sem retornar nenhum dado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130990/101).

> 2- No caso do `main()`, o tipo de retorno irá influenciar em algo, independente de ser 0, 10, 20, S, AB, 1000...? Porque numa função a parte o retorno irá influenciar a onde está fazendo sua chamada, certo? Aí fiquei com essa dúvida no retorno do `main()`.

Não entendi bem o que quer saber aqui. Leia isto:

- [Retorno da função main](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/386610/101)
- [Qual a forma correta de declarar uma função main()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95133/101)
- [Return 0 no Linux e Windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233990/101)
- [Existe diferença entre usar "return" ou "exit()" para encerrar a função "main()"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174312/101)

> 3- Mesmo para as funções do tipo `void` é necessário colocar um retorno?

Se está dizendo ter um comando `return`, não precisa, pode usar se a saída for condicional ou se quiser deixar mais explícito, mas não é comum fazer só pra deixar explícito. Uma finalização sempre há.

> 4- Só para confirmar, no caso o retorno está relacionado ao tipo que foi setado na função, correto? Então se eu setar como `int`, não adianta ter um retorno em `float` pois irá ocasionar erro, ok?

Vamos escrever de um jeito que faça mais sentido: o tipo do resultado que será usado em um `return` é o mesmo tipo que foi declarado na assinatura da função. Dito assim, é isto mesmo. Claro que existem alguns *casts* implícitos então alguns tipos podem ser usados que eles serão interpretados como o tipo declarado, mas isso é outra regra, independe de ser um retorno.

Se você não definir bem seu problema de forma clara seu códigos não serão claros. Por isso sugiro procurar entender as coisas de uma forma mais estruturada e tentar ser mais claro na hora de por no papel o que está pensando.