# Uso de "return 0" em funções void é realmente necessário?

Tags: c, tipagem, return, void

Gostaria de entender se existe a obrigatoriedade do `return 0` no final de uma função `void`.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void escrevaNaTela(); //Declarando a função
int main (){

    escrevaNaTela();
    return 0;
}
//definindo a função:
void escrevaNaTela(){ //não recebe parâmetros*
    printf("Teste de como fazer uma funcao\n");
    return 0; //Colocamos o return assium como na nossa main com o objetivo de mostrar que nosso código foi executado com êxito.
}
```

Se a própria função tem o tipo de retorno `void`, precisa ter o `return 0`?

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa retornar nada, nem o 0, nem mesmo precisa do comando `return` quando ele é a última linha da função.

C não manda dar erro nisso, mas estritamente falando está errado porque está retornando um número onde não se espera um retorno. Na prática nada de ruim acontecerá, até porque C tem tipagem fraca, então você pode retornar algo de um tipo onde se espera outro, e neste caso como se espera nada, o compilar certamente ignorará.

O comando `return` sozinho também não tem necessidade, a não ser que esteja dentro de algum bloco condicional.

Por curiosidade, os compiladores não exigem que se coloque `return 0` no `main()`. Não é que não precise, é que eles colocam para você se você não colocar. É um caso bem pontual. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233990/101).